# Mongo misses to catch insert triggers

Tags: python, mongodb, architecture, pymongo, eventtrigger

I am trying to build an architecture without any HTTPS requests that take a minimum (100 ms) to deliver a request to the backend server, so I decided to take help from mongo triggers now it's taking (20 ms) but miss some requests. I have 2 scripts

1. To Test Mongo Artitecture
2. To listen to mongo trigger and process that request

### Architecture Stats

| No of requests | Time Taken | Processed Requests | missed requests | docker swarm replicas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 949.51 | 996 | 4 | 1 |
| 3000 | 4387.24 | 2948 | 52 | 1 |
| 5000 | 10051.78 | 4878 | 122 | 1 |

### Worker Node Code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pymongo


connectionString = "mongodb://ml1:27017,ml1:27018,ml1:27019/magic_shop?replicaSet=mongodb-replicaset";
client           = MongoClient(connectionString)
db               = client.magic_shop        # test is my database
col              = db.req                   # Here spam is my collection

import socket
machine_name = socket.gethostname()
from datetime import datetime
import time

def processing_request(request):
    '''
    Description:
        Get the string, takes its length and run a loop 10 times of string length, and set the 
        response to processed.
        
    Input:
        request  (str) : Random String
        
    Output:
        Set value back to the mongo DB
            response: Processed
    '''
    for i in range(0,len(request)*10):
        pass
    
    

try:
    with db.req.watch([{'$match': {'operationType': 'insert'}}]) as stream:
        for values in stream:
            request_id = values['fullDocument']['request_id']
            request    = values['fullDocument']['request']
            myquery    = { "request_id": request_id }
            
            # Checking if not processed by other replica (Blocking System)
            if len(list(col.find({ 'request_id': request_id, 'CSR_NAME' : { "$exists": False}}))):
                newvalues  = { "$set": { "CSR_NAME": machine_name, "response": "Processing", "processing_time":datetime.today()} }

                # CSR Responding to the client
                col.update_one(myquery, newvalues)
                print(request_id)
                print(f"Processing {request_id}")
                # Now Processing Request
                processing_request(request)
                # Updating that work is done

                myquery   = { "request_id": request_id }
                newvalues = { "$set": {"response": "Request Processed Have a nice Day sir!", 'response_time':datetime.today()} }
                # CSR Responding to the client
                col.update_one(myquery, newvalues)
            
except pymongo.errors.PyMongoError:
    # The ChangeStream encountered an unrecoverable error or the
    # resume attempt failed to recreate the cursor.
    logging.error('...')
```

### Testing Code

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from PIL import Image
import io, random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime



db        = client.magic_shop            # test is my database
col       = db.req                       # Here spam is my collection
brust     = 5000
count     = 0 

for i in range(0, brust):
    random_id = int(random.random()*100000)
    image= {
                'request_id': random_id,
                'request': random.choice(requests),
                'request_time':datetime.today()
                }

    image_id = col.insert_one(image).inserted_id
    count+=1
    
    
print(f"Request Done {count}")
```

You can also get the complete code on Github

https://github.com/SohaibAnwaar/Docker-swarm

Comment: What is the exact question? How to avoid having missed requests?

Comment: ya! I need to process all the requests. But Mongo insert trigger is missing some of the requests.

Comment: Have you identified why Mongo is missing some of the requests?  Have you confirmed that the point of "failure" is Mongo and not something higher up the stack?

Comment: Yes! I checked all the things they are working fine.